# Plugin expecting Android manifest to be at /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Due to a lot of problems with old Cordova project setup. I tried to re-create a new project from scratch. However, when adding the plugin [cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/colibri-software/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation), it seems to expect `AndroidManifest.xml` to be at an I suppose an old location (`platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`) instead of where the manifest is now (`platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`). How do I make the plugin recognize the new location?

**EDIT**
I realized I referred to the wrong plugin. I meant [phonegap-backgroundjs](https://github.com/jocull/phonegap-backgroundjs)
. But the issue should be similar.

Answer (score 1):

If I make a new project, add the cordova-plugin-background-geolocation plugin and then add the android platform (version 7.1.0), it updates the manifest successfully. It installs the version 1.0.6 of the plugin.

You can check the plugin version you have using

```
cordova plugin list
```

If you have a older version can try to remove and then re-add the plugin?

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-background-geolocation
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-geolocation
```

Or you could try to use the 6.2.3 version of android platform instead of the latest one :

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@6.2.3
```

Comment: I was hoping to use a newer platform though. One of a newer version of the paid plugin requires >=7.0.0. And I'm having a lot of problem with plugin conflicts I was hoping a newer version of the platform and Cordova can somehow magically solves it.

Comment: Is there any reason not 6.4.0 but 6.2.3?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cordova-android bug (sort of).
It has some code to check if the project is Android Studio project or Eclipse project, and it does it by checking for certain folders in `platforms/android/`.
One of those folder is `res` folder.

Now, if you check that plugin, it's using a `source-file` tag for adding an image (https://github.com/colibri-software/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/master/plugin.xml#L32). That creates the res folder in the root of `platforms/android/` and confuses the cordova check, so it thinks it's an Eclipse project and look for the AndroidManifest.xml in the old location.

So your options are downgrade to cordova-android 6.4.0 or older, or fix the plugin to use `resource-file` tag instead of `source-file` tag for copying the image.

Comment: I just realized that I meant another plugin, (as edited in original post), but the issue should be similar. Also when I tried to remove some plugin after failing to add platform, I can't remove it. It will says `ENOENT: no such file or directory` when it tries to access `platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js`. Is that a similar problem? The assets folder should not be there?
Speaking of `res`, I used to have to move manually to overwritten folder in `platform/android/res`. Now with Android studio, both `res` and `assets` folder are in `platform/android/app/src/main/`?

Comment: Something is really wrong. Even when `cordova-plugin-device` is complaining about manifest not being there during a `cordova platform add android` command. This looks like a huge problem. Maybe I should just create a symlink?

Comment: Once a plugin create those folders it gets crazy and fails on any plugin. It’s already fixed, but not released yet

Comment: You seem to know a lot of details. I wish I'd know how to dig a little deeper. The Cordova stuff is a mystery to me, partly because I don't know Android. Are you on the Cordova dev team?

Comment: Yes, I'm part of the Cordova team

Answer (score 1):

Cordova Android 7.x kind of led to this issue (see the blog post here: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html). Each plugin that supports Android needs to update the path to the `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```
<!-- If an existing plugin.xml references AndroidManifest.xml like this -->
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">

<!-- it needs to change to the new path -->
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
```

But until each developer updates his/her plugin with the new path, you either need to downgrade to Cordova < 7.0 OR fork the offending plugins and make the changes yourself (and maybe submit a PR to the plugin devs so they can fix the issue). :-)